# How to extract a BLOB image and save it in the directory using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have saved images in my Database as BLOB, now I want to extract the images and save these into a directory.

Till now I'm able to view the BLOB image using following code.

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("genetech002" , "username" , "mypass");
$db = mysql_select_db("Mydatabase", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hs_hr_emp_picture WHERE emp_number = 5";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

I can see the image in my browser after executing the above script, but now I want to save this image in a directory (on my server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it with `file_put_contents()`.

```
file_put_contents("pic.jpg", $row['epic_picture']);
```

Comment: is file_put_contents() a php function?

Comment: Prepend `pic.jpg` with the path. Something like `/path/to/the/pic.jpg` or in Windows, `C:/path/to/the/pic.jpg`.